# Big Query how to convert string to date

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some date time type columns pushed into BQ as strings. They are in the format: `Wed Dec 20 02:54:35 GMT 2017`

I want them converted over to proper datetime so I can do some operations like calculate the time difference in milliseconds, etc. I have tried Date, cast, and nothing seems to work. They all give null back.

For instance, take these 2 date times:
`startTime = Wed Dec 20 02:54:35 GMT 2017`
`endTime = Wed Dec 20 02:54:36 GMT 2017`

I would like to calculate the time diff (in seconds or milliseconds).

Answer (score 3):

> I want them converted over to proper datetime so I can do some operations like calculate the time difference in milliseconds, etc.

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and ideally should  work for example you presented

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT startTime, endTime,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y', endTime), 
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y', startTime), 
    MILLISECOND
  ) diff_in_ms
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

You can test / play with it using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 'Wed Dec 20 02:54:35 GMT 2017' startTime, 'Wed Dec 20 02:54:36 GMT 2017' endTime
)
SELECT startTime, endTime,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y', endTime), 
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y', startTime), 
    MILLISECOND
  ) diff_in_ms
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

> also I am totally fine with removing the timezone alltogether

As looks like you have issue with PST - you can try below to eliminate timezone

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION removeTZ(val STRING) AS (
  REGEXP_REPLACE(val, r'(\w+ \w+ \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )\w+ (\d{4})', '\\1\\2')
);
SELECT startTime, endTime,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y', removeTZ(endTime)), 
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y', removeTZ(startTime)), 
    MILLISECOND
  ) diff_in_ms
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

Still you can test / play with same dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION removeTZ(val STRING) AS (
  REGEXP_REPLACE(val, r'(\w+ \w+ \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )\w+ (\d{4})', '\\1\\2')
);
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 'Wed Dec 20 02:54:35 GMT 2017' startTime, 'Wed Dec 20 02:54:36 GMT 2017' endTime
)
SELECT startTime, endTime,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y', removeTZ(endTime)), 
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y', removeTZ(startTime)), 
    MILLISECOND
  ) diff_in_ms
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

Both above query return same result (of course)

```sql
startTime                       endTime                         diff_in_ms   
Wed Dec 20 02:54:35 GMT 2017    Wed Dec 20 02:54:36 GMT 2017    1000
```

Note: the second solution (with time zone elimination) does not rely on predefined positions/length because time zone can be of different length. Rather it uses regular expression to identify timezone and remove it

Answer (score 1):

Try using `PARSE_TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y', 'Wed Dec 20 02:54:35 GMT 2017')
FROM yourTable;
```

As you can see from the verbosity of the above SQL, it is cumbersome to store your dates as text if you need to work them as actual dates.  Instead, always store dates/timestamps in proper date columns.

We can try parsing without the timezone:

```
SELECT
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y',
        CONCAT(SUBSTR(col, 1, 20), SUBSTR(col, 25, 4)))
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: I get an error: `Error: 3.17 - 3.57: Unrecognized function parse_timestamp`

Comment: The above should work if you are using Big Query with standard SQL.  Are you not doing that?

Comment: My bad, It was in legacy sql mode. I disabled that and then the function was available. However now it complains about the following: `Error: Invalid time zone: PST`

Comment: Strange, as `PST` is a [standard time zone abbreviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).  That you didn't get an error for `GMT` though shows that the query is at least working partially.

Comment: Its weird. I am located in PST timezone. Why does that have to do anything with the conversion when the original date string is in GMT format explicitly? Any ideas?

Comment: I even tried specifying an explicit timezone as follows: `PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y', startTime, 'EST') AS parsedSartTime`. It still fails with the same error: `Invalid time zone: PST`

Comment: I don't know this API well enough to give a hard answer.  Do any of your strings have `PST` in them?  This would be my guess.  If you don't care about the timezone, we can remove it before calling `PARSE_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: No I dont have any PST in any of the strings but also I am totally fine with removing the timezone alltogether. How would I drop the timezone portion?

Comment: @user1647697 I updated my answer with an option which removes the timezone completely.

Comment: @user1647697 - I don't think you being located in PST matters here! You definitelly have PST in your data. You can find it by doing something like `select startTime, endTime from \`project.dataset.table\` where startTime like  '%PST%' or endTime like '%PST%'`

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. For some reason some of the records have PST in them. I excluded them and it worked! Thanks again!

Comment: " it is cumbersome to store your dates as text if"  --> doing some quick tests it seems that the space involved to store it as a String is nearly 4 times more as when loading in Timestamp or Datetime format. Meaning that apart from being "cumbersome", it will cost you quite more money in BigQuery to store this table and to query it.